# setOnItemLongClickListener in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, listener

I just create long click listener for `listview`

```
chatListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            View getElement1 = ((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(0);
            int ChildCount = ((ViewGroup)getElement1).getChildCount();
            System.out.println(ChildCount);
        }
    });
```

and i get some error

> Error:(166, 86) error:  is not abstract
>   and does not override abstract method
>   onItemLongClick(AdapterView,View,int,long) in
>   OnItemLongClickListener Error:(168, 25) error:
>   onItemLongClick(AdapterView,View,int,long) in  cannot implement
>   onItemLongClick(AdapterView,View,int,long) in
>   OnItemLongClickListener return type void is not compatible with
>   boolean Error:(167, 13) error: method does not override or implement a
>   method from a supertype Error:(166, 45) error: incompatible types:
>    cannot be converted to
>   OnLongClickListener Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: add `android:longClickable="true"` in XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//You can Use this method
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
              int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

            return true;
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You must consume event. Write in bottom of onItemLongClick method

```
return true;
```

Comment: ok, already done. i add return true; and change void to boolean. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The XML for each item in the list if you use a custom XML must have `android:longClickable="true"` as well (or you can use the convenience method `chatListView.setLongClickable(true);)`.

Also add a boolean return statement in the `onItemLongClick` function i.e

> boolean   true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise

```
chatListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            View getElement1 = ((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(0);
            int ChildCount = ((ViewGroup)getElement1).getChildCount();
            System.out.println(ChildCount);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html, function should return a boolean value. Please check.